# Windows batch script to substitute tabs with 2 spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to substitute tab with 2 spaces in all files on a specified path using windows batch script. I see that it is not easy to enter tab character correctly into a batch file. Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: How does variable substitution work for you? **`%variable:[tab]=[space][space]%`**

Comment: Why is entering a tab character not easy? ever tried with the TAB key? what strange text editor are you using that does not support tabs?? Anyway, read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! You seem to confuse StackOverflow with a free coding service...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Corrected output of leading spaces.

The tricky part is to grab the `tab` char. May be...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Grab TAB character 
rem http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7898
set "TAB="
rem First, try the method for Windows XP
for /F "skip=4 delims=pR tokens=2" %%a in ('reg query hkcu\environment /v temp' ) do set "TAB=%%a"
rem Then, the method for newer versions
rem http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1733&p=6840#p6853
for /F "tokens=2 delims=0" %%a in ('shutdown /? ^| findstr /BC:E') do if not defined TAB set "TAB=%%a"

rem set desired number of spaces
set "SPACES=  "

pushd "your_desired_path"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B *.txt') do ( 
  > "output_%%~nxf" (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (%%~nxf) do (
      set "myData=%%i"
      set "myData=!myData:%TAB%=%SPACES%!"
      echo !myData!
    )
  )
  echo copy /y "output_%%~nxf" "%%~nxf" 
  echo del "output_%%~nxf" >NUL 2>NUL
)    

popd

endlocal
exit/B
```

Remove `echo` from `copy` and `del` lines above, if it seems to do the work.

Comment: I'd insert `set "TAB=%TAB: =%"` just before `for /F` loop against `shutdown /` as well as behind it.